# matching url to another url

Tags: php

I am faced with rather unusual situation

I will have url in any of the 3 formats:

1. http://example.com/?p=12
2. http://example.com/a-b/
3. http://example.com/a.html

Now, I need to match with a url like

1. http://example.com/?p=12&t=1
2. http://example.com/a-b/?t=1
3. http://example.com/a.html?t=1

How can I achieve this? Please help

I know I can use like:

```
stristr('http://example.com/?p=12','http://example.com/?p=12&t=1')
```

but this will also match when

```
http://example.com/?p=123 (as it matches p=12)
```

Help guys, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to accomplish this would be to use PHP's `parse_url()` and `parse_str()`.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Take your urls and run them through `parse_url()`, and take the resulting `$result['query']`. Run these through `parse_str()` and you'll end up with two associative arrays of the variable names and their values.

Basically, you'll want to return true if the `$result['path']`s match, and if any keys which are in both `$result['query']` contain the same values.

**code example:**

```
function urlMatch($url1, $url2)
{
    // parse the urls
    $r1 = parse_url($url1);
    $r2 = parse_url($url2);

    // get the variables out of the queries
    parse_str($r1['query'], $v1);
    parse_str($r2['query'], $v2);

    // match the domains and paths
    if ($r1['host'] != $r2['host'] || $r1['path'] != $r2['path'])
        return false;

    // match the arrays
    foreach ($v1 as $key => $value)
        if (array_key_exists($key, $v2) && $value != $v2[$key])
            return false;

    // if we haven't returned already, then the queries match
    return true;
}
```

Comment: @I-M-JM, there are clear and concise examples on the manual pages that Mala linked.

Comment: @I-M-JM, I wrote you a function that does what I think it is you need - it compares domains, paths, and then make sure that any variables that are defined in *both* query-strings must be equal.

Answer (score 0):

A very quick (and somewhat dirty) way to achieve this is via the following regex:

```
$regex = '#^' . preg_quote($url, '#') . '[?&$]#';
```

Where `$url` is the URL you need to search for. In the above, we look for the URL in the beginning of whatever the regex is matched upon, followed by either a `?`, a `&` or the end-of-line anchor. This is not bullet-proof but may be sufficient (@Mala [already posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415584/matching-url-to-another-url/5415672#5415672) the "right" approach).

Below, I've posted an [example of use](http://www.ideone.com/MHDQU) (and the result):

```
$urls = array(
    'http://example.com/?p=12',
    'http://example.com/a-b/',
    'http://example.com/a.html'
);
$tests = array(
    'http://example.com/?p=12&t=1',
    'http://example.com/a-b/?t=1',
    'http://example.com/a.html?t=1',
    'http://example.com/?p=123'
);

foreach ($urls as $url) {
        $regex = '#^' . preg_quote($url, '#') . '[?&$]#';
        print $url . ' - ' . $regex . "\n";
        foreach ($tests as $test) {
                $match = preg_match($regex, $test);
                print ' ' . ($match ? '+' : '-') . ' ' . $test . "\n";
        }
}
```

Result:

```
http://example.com/?p=12 - #^http\://example\.com/\?p\=12[?&$]#
 + http://example.com/?p=12&t=1
 - http://example.com/a-b/?t=1
 - http://example.com/a.html?t=1
 - http://example.com/?p=123
http://example.com/a-b/ - #^http\://example\.com/a-b/[?&$]#
 - http://example.com/?p=12&t=1
 + http://example.com/a-b/?t=1
 - http://example.com/a.html?t=1
 - http://example.com/?p=123
http://example.com/a.html - #^http\://example\.com/a\.html[?&$]#
 - http://example.com/?p=12&t=1
 - http://example.com/a-b/?t=1
 + http://example.com/a.html?t=1
 - http://example.com/?p=123
```